# Data must be query-set like

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm using an external database with Django. I had already written a script to populate the database. I was able to access this data with syncdb, and I have created a model for this data.

I am able to print the entire database, but using:

```
 TicketOdds.objects.all()[0]
```

raises the following exception:

> ValueError at /
>
> data must be QuerySet-like (have count and order_by) or support list(data) -- TicketOdds has neither

My model is:

```
class TicketOdds(models.Model):
    #id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ticket_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    ticket_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)
    odds = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    img_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    ticket_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ticket_odds'

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in xrange(100):
            yield i

    def __getitem__(self):
        return unicode(self)
```

What do I add to the model to make it "queryset-like"? I tried adding

```
def __iter__ (self):
```

for that specific purpose...
I must be missing something.

Comment: From what I can see you have been successful in using all the values in your db (`.all()`) with `TableData()`, however you're stuck trying to pass it a single object (`.all()[0]`), which results in that error. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't post the full traceback error message. I will just guide you along with the process to answer your question.

1. Look at the [source code](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/v0.15.0/django_tables2/tables.py#L37-L42). It will raise such error when `data` in the `TableData(data, table)` is not iterable. i.e. `__iter__` is not defined.
2. I doubt that you need to define the `__iter__` methods in your `Model` or `Model.Meta`, because [`QuerySet`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L162) which is an iterable class can be retrieved when you made this call: `TicketOdds.objects.all()`
3. Pass the `data` with the queryset you retrieved previously when you make the `TableData(data, table)`

Example:

```
TableData(TicketOdds.objects.all(), table)
```

> What do I add to the model to make it "queryset-like"?

You don't make your model "queryset-like", but rather you get the `QuerySet` from the models using the above example.

Comment: First of all, I haven't seen any pattern like this before. And I haven't use `django-tables2`. This might be just a partial answer or incorrect answer, but I hope you could try this and let us know if it works.

Comment: Super noob question... how to I get the traceback error message? manage.py shell?

Comment: Usually when `DEBUG = True`, they will print any error request into the page itself, "Yellow" color page. One of the printed message is the "Traceback" section. http://i.imgur.com/TWL6f.png